# Python: Using a multidimensional multiprocessing.manager.list()

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, multiprocessing

This might not be its intended use, but I would like to know how to use a multidimensional manager.list(). I can create on just fine, something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import manager

test = manager.list(manager.list())
```

however when ever I try to access the first element of the test list it returns the element's value and not its proxy object

```
test[0]  # returns [] and not the proxy, since I think python is running __getitem__.
```

Is there anyway for me to get around this and use the manager.list() in this way?

Comment: is there any reason why you are using nested manager.list()? I thought using manager.list() returns the listed objects anyway?

Comment: @ha9u63ar I need a list of manager.list() to accomplish my task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`multiprocessing` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list) has a note on this:

> **Note**
>
> Modifications to mutable values or items in dict and list proxies will
>   not be propagated through the manager, because the proxy has no way of
>   knowing when its values or items are modified. To modify such an item,
>   you can re-assign the modified object to the container proxy:
>
> ```
> # create a list proxy and append a mutable object (a dictionary) 
> lproxy = manager.list() 
> lproxy.append({})
> # now mutate the dictionary 
> d = lproxy[0]
> d['a'] = 1 
> d['b'] = 2
> # at this point, the changes to d are not yet synced, but by
> # reassigning the dictionary, the proxy is notified of the change 
> lproxy[0] = d
> ```

So, the only way to use a multidimensional list is to actually reassign any changes you make to the second dimension of the list back to the top-level list, so instead of:

```
test[0][0] = 1
```

You do:

```
tmp = test[0]
tmp[0] = 1
test[0] = tmp
```

Not the most pleasant way to do things, but you can probably write some helper functions to make it a bit more tolerable.

**Edit:**

It seems the reason that you get a plain list back when you append a `ListProxy` to another `ListProxy` is because of how pickling Proxies works. `BaseProxy.__reduce__` creates a `RebuildProxy` object, which what actually is used to unpickle the `Proxy`. `RebuildProxy` looks like this:

```
def RebuildProxy(func, token, serializer, kwds):
    '''
    Function used for unpickling proxy objects.

    If possible the shared object is returned, or otherwise a proxy for it.
    '''
    server = getattr(process.current_process(), '_manager_server', None)

    if server and server.address == token.address:
        return server.id_to_obj[token.id][0]
    else:
        incref = (
            kwds.pop('incref', True) and
            not getattr(process.current_process(), '_inheriting', False)
            )
        return func(token, serializer, incref=incref, **kwds)
```

As the docstring says, if the unpickling is occuring inside a manager server, the actual shared object is created, rather than the `Proxy` to it. This is probably a bug, and [there is actually one filed](http://bugs.python.org/issue6766) against this behavior already.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I understood this already about proxy lists. What my question really wanted to know is how to to get back the proxy object that holds my list when I call test[0] not the value the proxy holds.

Comment: @user2909415 I'm pretty sure the inner lists don't get proxy objects, they're just stored as standard lists. Let me double check that in the code and update my answer.

Comment: @user2909415 I added some instrumentation to the `multiprocessing` code that verify that when you send a proxy object to the server via `_callmethod`, the referent (e.g. the underlying list) is all that ends up being received by the server. I haven't been able to pin down *why* that's happening, though.

Comment: So I guess the easiest thing in my situation is just to create a proxy class of my own that holds a proxy list and register it to my own manager and use it that way. I really wish multiprocessing was as easy to use as the rest of python...

Comment: @user2909415 It looks like this is a bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue6766. The issue is that when you unpickle a Proxy *inside a manager server*, you get the referent itself, rather than the Proxy. So, when the manager is passed a Proxy and goes to unpickle it, it ends up with the referent rather than the proxy itself. This is a problem if you actually want the Proxy object to remain so you can get it later.

Comment: @user2909415 It's a few weeks late, but I posted a workaround for that bug [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29800456/2073595). It will let you get the actual `Proxy` object back from the `Manager`.