# Python: How to pass an Autoproxy object

Tags: python, proxy, multiprocessing

I need to pass the proxy of an object to another object but whenever I do this all the other object gets is the referent of the proxy and not the proxy itself. This is something similar to what I am trying to do:

```
import multiprocessing.managers as m

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.manager = MyManager()
        self.manager.register('Bar', Bar)
        self.manager.start()
        self.bar = self.manager.Bar()
        self.bar.set_proxy(self.bar)


class Bar(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.proxy = None

    def set_proxy(self, proxy):
        self.proxy = proxy

class MyManager(m.BaseManager):
    pass

test = Foo()
```

whenever I do this the value in `self.proxy` is the instance of Foo that I created and not the proxy that was returned by the manager.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. As you said, the problem is somewhere before `self.bar.set_proxy(...)`, so can you please post the `MyManager()` class?

Comment: the MyManager() class is just a subclass on multiprocessing.BaseManager(), but I'll add it in if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of design flaw, or perhaps [a bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue6766), in the way `Proxy` instances get unpickled. Right now, if the unpickling code see you're running inside a `Manager`, it gives you the referent when you unpickle, rather than the `Proxy`:

```
def RebuildProxy(func, token, serializer, kwds):
    '''
    Function used for unpickling proxy objects.

    If possible the shared object is returned, or otherwise a proxy for it.
    '''
    server = getattr(process.current_process(), '_manager_server', None)

    if server and server.address == token.address:
        return server.id_to_obj[token.id][0] # This returns the referent
    else:
        incref = (
            kwds.pop('incref', True) and
            not getattr(process.current_process(), '_inheriting', False)
            )
        return func(token, serializer, incref=incref, **kwds) # This returns the Proxy
```

Sometimes this might be desirable, but sometimes its not, like it is in your case. You can work around it by replacing the `ReduceProxy` function that does the unpickling in your program:

```
import multiprocessing.managers as m
from multiprocessing import process

def RebuildProxyNoReferent(func, token, serializer, kwds):
    '''
    Function used for unpickling proxy objects.

    The Proxy object is always returned.
    '''
    incref = (
    kwds.pop('incref', True) and
    not getattr(process.current_process(), '_inheriting', False)
    )
    return func(token, serializer, incref=incref, **kwds)

m.RebuildProxy = RebuildProxyNoReferent  # Monkey-patch it

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.manager = MyManager()
        self.manager.register('Bar', Bar)
        self.manager.start()
        self.bar = self.manager.Bar()
        print(type(self.bar))
        self.bar.set_proxy(self.bar)


class Bar(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.proxy = None

    def set_proxy(self, proxy):
        print("got {}".format(type(proxy)))
        self.proxy = proxy

class MyManager(m.BaseManager):
    pass

test = Foo()
```

If you don't want to monkey-patch, you can also subclass `BaseProxy`, though its a bit more work:

```
import multiprocessing.managers as m
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseProxy
from multiprocessing import process

def RebuildProxyNoReferent(func, token, serializer, kwds):
    '''
    Function used for unpickling proxy objects.

    If possible the shared object is returned, or otherwise a proxy for it.
    '''
    incref = (
    kwds.pop('incref', True) and
    not getattr(process.current_process(), '_inheriting', False)
    )
    return func(token, serializer, incref=incref, **kwds)

class MyProxy(BaseProxy):
    _exposed_ = ("set_proxy",)
    def set_proxy(self, arg):
        self._callmethod('set_proxy', (arg,))

    def __reduce__(self):
        ret = super(MyProxy, self).__reduce__()
        # RebuildProxy is the first item in the ret tuple.
        # So lets replace it, just for our proxy.
        ret = (RebuildProxyNoReferent,) + ret[1:]
        return ret

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.manager = MyManager()
        self.manager.register('Bar', Bar, MyProxy)
        self.manager.start()
        self.bar = self.manager.Bar()
        print(type(self.bar))
        self.bar.set_proxy(self.bar)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. I think this is the third time now that you have successfully answered one of my questions and the second time you figured it was a bug; you're amazing!